# Multiple table join, facebook like news wall

Tags: php, sql, join, pdo

Ok I am creating a social networking site similar to Instagram. So I want to fetch post from db but only show posts from people the currently logged in user is following just like Instagram. I've tried using a php join and it didn't work, though I think my query is wrong because it's bringing out false results. Please any answer to this would be nice as it would also help others. This is what I've tried to do but don't know where am wrong.

```
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT n.*, c.*, n.id AS nid, c.id AS cid FROM
              newsfeeds n JOIN connections2 c ON c.user1 = n.userId OR c.user2 = n.userId
              WHERE n.userId = c.user1 OR n.userId = c.user2 ORDER BY nid DESC");
    $query->execute();
```

I have two table. One is connections2 for users connection and the other is newsfeeds table for post.

This is an image of my db
This one for connections table
[this is where all followed people would be](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6YzaeYbyV7sell6WWE3X19YZTA)
This one for feeds table
[This is the post table](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6YzaeYbyV7sNjQ5RmZkV1V0eGM)

Comment: why did you have the same conditions in WHERE and in ON condition of JOIN?

Comment: Can you please show sample data and a desired result?  I've no idea what you're trying to do, or what might be the issue.  As a side-note, your `WHERE` clause is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: Oh ok am not too good with join statements but the same condition in the where clause and on is meant to show if the connections id match

Comment: Am trying to create an instagram like feeds page

Comment: What he meant, is to show table definition, sample of records in your table and a sample of the result you wish to get.

Comment: a php join. sounds shiny.

Comment: @Lamar i have added to my question images to my tables. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would this query work?

```
SELECT n.id AS nid,
n.userid,
n.news,
n.news_image,
n.access,
n.date,
c.id AS cid,
c.user1,
c.user2,
c.time,
c.status
FROM newsfeeds n
INNER JOIN connections c ON (c.user1 = n.userid OR c.user2 = n.userid)
ORDER BY n.id DESC;
```

However, why are you checking the connections table, and why are you checking it for two users? Wouldn't it be easier to check just the newsfeed table for the currently logged in user? Unless is misunderstand your connections table, this could work:

```
SELECT n.id,
n.userid,
n.news,
n.news_image,
n.access,
n.date,
FROM newsfeeds n
WHERE n.userid = "X"
ORDER BY n.id DESC;
```

(Replace the "X" with your actual user ID for the currently logged in user)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but am checking the connections table in order to show post from only connected users with the currently logged in user and also the users post.

Comment: thanks but the first query didn't work. when i did a count with it it gave me 5 instead of 2.

Comment: Why are you expecting 2 records instead of 5? Which are the three records you are not expecting? If the user ID on the newsfeed table is in either of the connection table userid fields then it will be displayed. So, what is different about the 2 fields you are expecting?